# delete button layout

Tags: php

I've gone through a solution on processing checkboxes and think I understand what I need to do, but I have a problem where I put my delete button in this code.  Here is my table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Camera Name</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Video Size</th>
        <th>Video Length</th>
        <th>
            <button type="submit" class="deletebutton" name="delete_video" value="Delete" title="Delete the selected videos" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</button><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="radioselectall" title="Select All" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

 <?php

for($i=0;$i<$num_videos;$i++)
{
       //do stuff
       //Note: I'm looping here to build the table from the server
?>              
        <tr >
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo setlocalTime($result_videos[$i]["video_datetime"]); ?> 
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo ByteSize($result_videos[$i]["video_size"]); ?>
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                <?php echo strTime($result_videos[$i]["video_length"]); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form name="myform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
                <input type="checkbox" name="radioselect" title="Mark this video for deletion"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="video_name" value="<?php echo $result_videos[$i]["video_name"]; ?>" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
...
```

Notice that I loop through and populate the table from the server but the header is not looping through obviously.  I used to put the delete button in the form and on each line of the table.  But now since I want multi-delete I create checkboxes on each line and put the delete button in the header.  I should also note that `video_name` is crucial so I know what videos to delete.

But that is the problem, since I don't have a submit (delete) in the form (that is in the loop) I can't process theses checkboxes.  Instead I only have the delete button Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form should go around the whole table, and rather than have a hidden input for the name you can have it in the checkbox's name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="radioselect[<?php echo $result_videos[$i]['video_name']; ?>]" />
```

Then, in your PHP script that receives the POST request, `$_POST['radioselect']` will be an array. You can then use:

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST['radioselect']) as $k) { ... }
```

This will loop through the selected checkboxes. You get the `video_name` in `$k` and you can handle it as you would a single deletion.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put the video's ID in the name of its delete checkbox. Then you can read through the checkboxes you received and parse the video names out of them.